# Obtain data deep in structures C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I just encountered something rather weird.
When I have a pointer to a structure which contains another pointer to a structure of the same type, if I want to get the data from the "second" structure (if you didn't get what I mean, maybe the diagram below will describe it better)...

```
                      1
          ptr ---> |------|       2
                   | next ---> |------|
                   | data |    | next |
                   |------|    | data | <= data which i desire to get 
                               |------|
```

How should I access the desired data if I don't really want to declare another pointer variable ?

What if the desired data is even more "deeper"?

I tried something like this for a test, but it feels a little.. "broken looking" to me and I'm really surprised by the fact that there were no compiler warnings:

**ptr2struct.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Structure structure;
struct Structure {
    int data;
    structure *next;
};

int main()
{
    structure *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));

    /* First structure */
    ptr->data = 1;
    ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(ptr->next));

    /* Second structure */
    ptr->next->data = 2;
    ptr->next->next = malloc(sizeof(ptr->next->next));

    /* Third structure, why not */
    ptr->next->next->data = 3;
    ptr->next->next->next = NULL;

    printf("ptr->data = %d\n", ptr->data);
    printf("ptr->next->data = %d\n", ptr->next->data);
    printf("ptr->next->next->data = %d\n", ptr->next->next->data);

    return 0;
}
```

I guess there is a bunch of better ways of doing this, I know that the best way would be maybe to traverse through or declare additional pointers, but what if the constraints don't allow such methods?
What would be the overall best way to achieve this?

BTW this is not my HW, just curiosity :)

Have a great day and thx for the tips!

Comment: I'm surprised it works too cos `malloc(sizeof(ptr))` is wrong - it gets the size of the pointer rather than what is being pointed at

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are asking.  It seems like it could venture into an opinion-based answer.  You've basically described a Linked List but haven't really described a problem or issue since all of your constraints are theoretical and ill-defined.

Comment: Likewise with `malloc(sizeof(ptr->next));`, also the size of a pointer, not the structure. And `malloc(sizeof(ptr->next->next))`, etc. The "better" way to do this starts with a better understanding of [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).

Comment: Have you explored a macro based solution? It could help clean up the syntax a bit.

Comment: better way? I don't know if this is better but it seems elegant. Make a linked list struct whose only concrete data member is a pointer to list head. Also add function pointers to a get function that takes an int argument about how deep you want to go into the list and returns the data at the desired depth. But again as someone pointed out, this is my *opinion*. What you are doing is much more commonplace

Comment: @ChrisTurner It works because the allocator doesn't occupy the exact memory space, but leaves some unused space, normally for standard alignment, leaving enough room to store the small structure without out-of-bounds access. Substantially an UB commonly seen on many systems.

Comment: In short, i would like to ask if obtaining deeply data stored (like in example) can be and is done like this? would you consider this somewhat good/applicable practise?

Comment: @RollAndSchullz No, it isn't. Typically a separate pointer is used to address the head node, then "walked" down the list by picking up `next` values from the current node until you find the node you're interested in (or the end of the list). Honestly, code that has `next->next` is chaining is rarely helpful, and often a recipe for an unchecked pointer dereference leading to *undefined behavior*. Not to say it is never done (a tree rotation algorithm, for example), but it is an exception, and shouldn't be the rule.

Comment: So it shouldnt be used in something large or repetitively across code, but what if its used just onceto, for ex. change the data or assign the data?

Comment: @AneeshDurg macro based solution? i dont know what you mean sry, but ill look it up!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that is wrong is this:

```
structure *ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));
```

That allocates enough space to hold a `ptr` which is a pointer, you need

```
structure *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Having allocated everything correctly, access things in the first element like this:

```
ptr->data; // the data
ptr->next; // pointer to the next struct in the chain
```

Access stuff in the second `struct` like this

```
ptr->next->data; // data in the second struct
ptr->next->next; // pointer to the third struct
```

And so on.

Having just read some of the comments on the question, I should add that `ptr->next->next` is inherently dangerous unless you know for a fact that both `ptr` and `ptr->next` are non null. Also, `malloc` doesn't guarantee zeroed memory so after calling `malloc` you should always ensure that the `next` pointer is `NULL`.

If you have a long chain, and the last item is signified by having a `NULL` `next` you can iterate through the chain nicely with a `for` loop e.g.

```
for (structure* current = ptr ; current != NULL ; current = current->next)
{
    printf("%d\n", current->data);
}
```

Or, if you want to find the `n`th item

```
structure* ptrAtIndex(structure* start, int index) 
{
    for (structure* current = ptr, int i = 0 ; current != NULL ; current = current->next, i++)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            return current;
        }
    }
    return NULL; // The chain wasn't long enough
}
```

Comment: you might want to edit your answer for the sake of completeness to address the OP's question about a better way to access data deep in the linked structure without chaining `->next`

Comment: @Srini Yes, just thinking about that

Comment: Thanks for pointing (heheh) that I forgot the asterisk :)
I meant the question more like, would you use the way i shown without declaring another pointer, or declaring it.

Comment: @RollAndSchullz Check out  my examples for walking down the list. I've written for loops like that many times.